# How to set Thread name using anonymous method?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have the following code to run my instructions from anonymous method for threading

```
new Thread(delegate()
    {
        //my code
    }).Start();
```

For debugging purpose I want to set the thread name in the scenario above, how can I accomplish that?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Thread(delegate()
    {
        //my code
    })
   {
      Name = "whatever"
   }.Start();
```

Or let's make it readable.

```
var thread = Thread(delegate()
             {
                 //my code
             });
thread.Name = "whatever";
thread.Start();
```

Comment: @mclaassen Unfortunately, I hit my reputation cap.. :(

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'd say this is a "First world problem" ahah

Comment: @TopinFrassi I was about to say the exact same thing!

Answer (score 1):

The delegate has nothing to do with the threads name:

```
Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
{
    //my code
});

t.Name = "ThreadName";
t.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name(v=vs.110).aspx

```
   var thread = Thread delegate()
       {
           //my code
       });
   thread.Name="foo";
   thread.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three options.

- Don't put `.Start()` on the same line.

```
var thread = new Thread(delegate()
    {
        //my code
    });
thread.Name = "MyName";
thread.Start();
```

- Write a extension method

```
static void Start(this Thread thread, string name)
{
    thread.Name = name;
    thread.Start();
}

//Elsewhere
new Thread(delegate()
{
    //my code
}).Start("MyName");
```

- [Use a object initilizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25210581/80274) (did not even think to do that, saw the answer as I was writing mine.)